# Best algorithm for Decisional 4-XOR problem?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, search-algorithms

**Decisional 4-XOR Problem**: Assume $M>>n$  (e.g. $M=50n$ ). Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$
be sets consisting of $M$-bit elements. Each set has order exactly $2^n$. Decide whether or not there exists $a_i \in A_i$ such that $$a_1 \oplus a_2\oplus a_3\oplus a_4=0$$

The standart methods solves the search version of the problem in $O(2^{2n})$. Is there a better way to solve the decisional problem.

(Even a probabilistic algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

For this setting of parameters, I don't believe any method with better time complexity is known in the research literature.

Comment: In fact solving the problem in case $M=4n$ is enough.  Considering the first 4n bits of the numbers, if there is no $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ such that  first 4n bits of $ a_1 \oplus a_2 \oplus a_3 \oplus a_4$   is zero, then we solve the main problem.  That means we solve the problem with probability > 1/2

Comment: So, any probabilistic algorithm for decisional 4-XOR problem with time better than $n^2$ helps me.